# How to create a separate admin interface for blogs in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, rails-routing, user-roles

I need to create some routes for my blog website such that normal user can only read the posts and products. while super admin creates admins to moderate posts. How can i achieve that in rails? 
I want 
    myapp.com/admin to bring me to log in page for admins. 
    Only super admin can manage moderators.

So far, I have a controller in 'app/controller/admin/home_controller'
which has index action for viewing all posts and users for admin.

Comment: The more i search the more confuse i get.

Comment: Start by learning the difference between authorization and authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a before filter before your action so that each time a admin try to hit that url he/she should get redirected to admin_login_url

```
before_filter :check_role

private
 def check_role
    unless current_user.role=='super_admin'
      redirect_to admin_login_url
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to share what i actually did after reading tons of approaches just in case if anyone is stuck where i was. Hopefully helps:

1. Create a new controller in 'app/controllers/'. This controller is only      responsible for GET requests.
2. Remove Create, Update, Delete methods from the controllers in 'app/controllers/', as these will be only accessible to admins.
3. Create a new admin_controller.rb in 'app/controllers/admin/'. Add authentications here.
4. Create new controllers(inherited from AdminsController) per model in the same directory and put the admin operations there.

   class AdminPostsController < AdminsController